# Replacing a specific field using awk, sed or any POSIX tool

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep, tr

I have a huge file1, which has values as follows:

```
a 1
b 2
c 3
d 4
e 5
```

I have another huge file2, which is colon delimited with seven fields as follows:

```
a:2543:2524:2542:252:536365:54654
c:5454:5454:654:54:87:54
d:87:65:1:98:32:87
```

I want to search the lines for the variables of file1 and replace its value in the 7th column in file2 so the output should be as follows:

```
a:2543:2524:2542:252:536365:1
c:5454:5454:654:54:87:3
d:87:65:1:98:32:4
```

Comment: What code/script have you tried? Is really the `file1` as simple as it seems? You do not expect us to write the code for you, do you?

Comment: Replace with what? Is `file1` a mapping from `a` to `1` etc., and if so, why is `54654` replaced by `1`?

Comment: Ah, I see - according to the first column of `file2`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I came up with a solution; ended up with a couple of lines of code. Maybe there is a better way to do it.But this works !

```
while read line ; do 
  var1=`echo $line| awk '{print $1}'`
  var2=`echo $line| awk '{print $2}'`
  awk -v var1="$var1" -v var2="$var2" -F ':' 'BEGIN { OFS = ":"} $1==var1 {sub(".*",var2,$7)}{print}' file2 > file2.tmp
  mv file2.tmp file2
done < file1
cat file2
```

Comment: Much more efficient to replace `read line` with `read -r var1 var2 _`. (Of course, it would be better than *that* to have just one `awk` doing all the work, instead of one invocation per line, but that's a separate issue).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this `awk` will work, assuming the files are as posted

```
awk -F: 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$0;next;}a[$1]{$0=a[$1]}1' file1 file2
a:2543:2524:2542:252:536365:1
c:5454:5454:654:54:87:3
d:87:65:1:98:32:4
```

Comment: Unfortunately that didnt work for me, but I came up with a solution which I posted below.

Answer (score 0):

This should work - it assumes both files are sorted on the first column - I'd be very interested in any performance comparisons with your solution for very large files - both speed and memory - --complement is linux-specific but easily replaced if not available

```
file0=$1 #file with single value
file1=$2 #file with 6th value to be replaced
# normalize on colon delimiter
tr ' ' : <$file0|
# join on first field
join -t: $file1 -|
# delete column 7
cut --complement -d: -f7
```

Comment: I'd consider quoting your expansions -- and you might consider using `<(sort "$file1")` and `< <(sort "$file0")` to guarantee the sort constraint.